# Is it possible to change kramdown’s use of “↩” for footnote backlinks?

Tags: kramdown

Kramdown uses “↩” (U+21A9) to link from footnotes back to the main text. Under OS X 10.10.3 and iOS 8.3, though, this character appears in Emoji form (↩️, if your browser supports it). [Like John Gruber](https://twitter.com/charlietuna/status/590362985861812225), I’d like to replace the bare U+21A9 with the two-character sequence U+21A9 U+FE0E, which will [force it to render in “text style”](http://mts.io/2015/04/21/unicode-symbol-render-text-emoji/). (That’s what I did in the title and the first sentence of this question.)

I don’t see a [kramdown configuration option](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/options.html) to change this character. Is it possible to change this in kramdown itself, or do I need to futz around manually with kramdown’s output?

If your browser doesn't show the Emoji, here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of kramdown 1.8, this is possible with the [`--footnote_backlink`](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/options.html) option.

Prior to 1.8, it's not possible natively. You can do some post-processing in `sed` relatively easily, however, and add in the HTML entity encoding of U+FE0E.

```
$ kramdown file.txt | sed 's/&#8617;/\&#8617;\&#65038;/' > file.html
```

If you already have a folder full of HTML files, you can edit them in place with Perl:

```
find . -name "*.html" -print0 | \
xargs -0 perl -pi -e 's/&#8617;/&#8617;&#65038;/g'
```

For the “double-encoded” entities you might find in RSS or Atom feeds,

```
find . -name "*.xml" -print0 | \
xargs -0 perl -pi -e 's/&amp;#8617;/&amp;#8617;&amp;#65038;/g'
```

Comment: I’ve opened this as [issue 247](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/issues/247)—thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The kramdown maintainer [isn’t going to fix this](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/issues/247), so it looks like Kyle’s solution is the way to go.